# How to add values to a new column based on a list with values from another column

Tags: python, pandas

So let's say I have something like this:~

```
A    
v1   
v2
v3
v3
v4
```

And i have list that's like this:

```
python_list_1 = ["v1","v2"]
python_list_2 = ["v3","v4"]
```

And now I want to make something along these likes:

```
df['A'] = np.where(df['B'] in python_list_1 , "XT")
df['A'] = np.where(df['B'] in python_list_2 , "AB")

A    B
v1   XT
v2   XT
v3   AB
v3   AB
v4   AB
```

Any tips for a pandas newbie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for conditions, also is possible set `default` value if some value not matched both conditions:

```
print (df)
    A
0  v1
1  v2
2  v3
3  v3
4  v4
5  v5

python_list_1 = ["v1","v2"]
python_list_2 = ["v3","v4"]

m1 = df['A'].isin(python_list_1)
m2 = df['A'].isin(python_list_2)
df['B'] = np.select([m1, m2], ["XT", "AB"], default=df['A'])
print (df)
    A   B
0  v1  XT
1  v2  XT
2  v3  AB
3  v3  AB
4  v4  AB
5  v5  v5
```

---

```
df['B'] = np.select([m1, m2], ["XT", "AB"], default='no match')
print (df)
    A         B
0  v1        XT
1  v2        XT
2  v3        AB
3  v3        AB
4  v4        AB
5  v5  no match
```

---

`numpy alternative` with [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
m1 = np.in1d(df['A'], python_list_1)
m2 = np.in1d(df['A'], python_list_2)
df['B'] = np.select([m1,m2],[ "XT", "AB"], default='no match')
print (df)
    A         B
0  v1        XT
1  v2        XT
2  v3        AB
3  v3        AB
4  v4        AB
5  v5  no match
```

Comment: Glad can help you!

Answer (score 0):

How about with `apply` function

```
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda d: "XT" if d in l1 else ("AB" if d in l2 else "<NA>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use `if-elif-else` to create a list which can be added to dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"A" : ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v3", "v4"]})
python_list_1 = ["v1","v2"]
python_list_2 = ["v3","v4"]

outlist = []
for i in data["A"]:
    if i in python_list_1:
        outlist.append("XT")
    elif i in python_list_2:
        outlist.append("AB")
    else: 
        outlist.append("")
data["B"] = outlist
print(data)
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0  v1  XT
1  v2  XT
2  v3  AB
3  v3  AB
4  v4  AB
```

Can also use list comprehension for this:

```
data['B'] = [   "XT" if item in python_list_1 
                else ("AB" if item in python_list_2 else "")   
                for item in data["A"]]
```